# Do those wireless usb adapters have lag/performance issues?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking

Are there noticable issues at least for gaming and streaming video?
And that compared to wired straight to router.

(I'm talking about the adapters to connect to the router, not the ones that connect to mobile networks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, your Internet connection is going to be the limiting factor, not your home network.  Home Internet access tends to be between 768 kbps up to 6 Mbps, but wireless networks usually rate 54 Mbps (you don't get this full speed, but even at only 1/9th of the rated speed it's still faster than the Internet connection).

Given that information, I wouldn't worry about it unless you have a very bad wireless signal at the place where you need it.

Comment: Oh I have a good signal, I'm more worried if wireless adds me extra lag for the games.

Answer (score 0):

It is always slower to connect to a Local Area Network by wireless rather than by ethernet (wired). That said, it really depends on how good your wireless connection is and also on the remote server. And of course speed is also dependent on what throughput you're getting from your Internet Service Provider. A slow DSL connection will be even slower wirelessly.

Example: We connect the Xbox and PS3 wirelessly. The Xbox online component is usually quite good - the boys have no issues playing multiplayer games and I can watch Netflix streaming movies with no problem. The PS3 (located one shelf down from the Xbox) has generally awful connectivity.

Maybe you could be a tad more specific about your hardware, your Internet connection, and what you're trying to do. If you're considering purchasing a USB wireless adapter, which one? For what operating system?

Comment: I was talking it more generally, like will the wireless add more milliseconds of lag when I'm playing games and is it worth to drill hole through a wall to get rid of the extra lag. There should be no problems with the signal as my mother's laptop has full strenght where I want to put my desktop.

Comment: You sound like a pretty hard-core gamer. In that case I would say yes, go ahead and run ethernet. *After* checking with your mother. ;-)